# background-attachment: fixed in Firefox or Edge versus Chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-transforms, background-position, background-attachment

```css
body {
    height: 150vh;
}

#hero {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    height: 100vh;
}

#hero .hero-image {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 95%;
}

#hero .hero-image:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#hero .skewhero-mask {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10vw;
    width: 45vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: skew(24deg) translateX(0vh) translateY(0%);
}

#hero .skewhero-parallax {
    transform: translateX(0vh);
    width: 200%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#hero .skewhero-image {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131);
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 110% auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    transform-origin: right top;
    transform: skew(-24deg);
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
    <div class="hero-image">
    </div>
    <div class="skewhero-mask">
      <div class="skewhero-parallax">
        <div class="skewhero-image"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I am really stuck with this one. I'm designing a parallax effect where I shift the `background-position` property of a fixed background using jQuery. The jQuery isn't at fault here, so I won't include it here to reduce the complexity of the question.

In Chrome, I get the desired effect. In Firefox or Edge, it's a nightmare. I have not tested it on Opera as of yet. When removing the `background-attachment: fixed` from the class `.skewhero-image` in those browsers, I notice there's no difference whatsoever. The property doesn't do anything, because when I remove the same property in Chrome, I get the same undesirable result as in the other browsers.

How can I change my code as to achieve the exact same effect as I have now in Chrome, but in all other desktop browsers as well? Mobile browsers excluded.

Basically, the image of the cat must *not* move, only the *container* surrounding it. In Chrome, this works as intended. In Firefox or Edge, the cat moves with the container, it isn't fixed to the viewport.

Edit: I have found out that leaving out **all** `transform` properties, from itself and all parents, fixes the image to the viewport. Anything to remedy this?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
 "use strict";
 var $skp = $('.skewhero-parallax');
 var $skm = $('.skewhero-mask');
 var $hi = $('.hero-image');

 function calcParallax() {
   var $scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
   $skm.css({'transform':'skew(24deg) translateX(-' + (0.445 * $scroll) + 'px)'});
   $skp.css({'transform':'translateY(' + $scroll + 'px)'});
   $hi.css({'transform':'translateY(' + $scroll + 'px)'});
 }

 $(window).on('scroll', function () {
  calcParallax();
 });

 $(window).resize(function() {
  calcParallax();
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 150vh;
}

#hero {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    height: 100vh;
}

#hero .hero-container {
 height: 95%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#hero .hero-container:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 height: 95%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}

#hero .hero-image {
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 will-change: transform;
}

#hero .skewhero-mask {
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 10vh;
 width: 45vw;
 overflow: hidden;
 transform: skew(24deg) translateX(0vh);
 will-change: transform;
}

#hero .skewhero-parallax {
 width: 200%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 transform: translateY(0px);
 will-change: transform;
}

#hero .skewhero-image {
 background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: 110% auto;
 background-position: 0px -35px;
 transform-origin: right top;
 transform: skew(-24deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="hero">
    <div class="hero-container">
        <div class="hero-image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="skewhero-mask">
      <div class="skewhero-parallax">
        <div class="skewhero-image"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have found an alternative solution to fix my problem. Also, it seems browsers are able to deal with this solution a lot better. `background-attachment:fixed` is causing serious performance issues. This is because the browsers have to repaint the entire image when scrolled. [Source #1](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property/) and [Source #2](https://medium.com/@ArthurFinkler/css-animations-translate-vs-absolute-positioning-and-background-position-dd39fbdeade5). I have tested this myself and can confirm there's heavy lag when scrolling. I have started using the `transform: translate()` property, which is a lot more optimized for this as browsers don't have to repaint the entire image.

As I want to animate my parallax effect with jQuery, I've mimicked the fixed background effect in my code. I have added a code snippet of the desired effect, which works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version of Firefox you are using but I just created codepen and it is working fine

```
<https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZgpgZP>
```

If you are still have problem, please describe in details

Comment: Firefox Quantum 68.0.1 (64-bits) and Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0. It doesn't work on my end. The cat in `skewhero-image` still isn't fixed to the viewport, but scrolls along.

Comment: I am using the same version, did you check the codepen link, is it working right on there

Comment: This is on Firefox, notice how the eyes are still visible when scrolling: https://prnt.sc/okgeiq 
This is on Chrome, notice how the eyes are gone when scrolling: https://prnt.sc/okgepk